# series not showing highcharts

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

I have a problem in showing the series value for a column chart .
I did the following method to format my data to an object format but still not working. Do you have any clue ?
please note that my json object is an array of array of 2 elements.

```
function getSeries(data) {
    var tab = [];
    var l = data.length;
    for (var i = 0; i < l; i++) {

            var tabb =[];
            for (var  j=0 ; j< l ;j++){
                if (i==j) tabb.push(data[i][1]); else tabb.push(0);
            }
                    tab.push("{name: '"+data[i][0]+"' , data : ["+tabb+"]}");

        }
    return tab ;
     }
```

Comment: Please post the json object content which is `data`

Comment: Change: `tab.push("{name: '"+data[i][0]+"' , data : ["+tabb+"]}");` to `tab.push({name: data[i][0], data : tabb});`. Also, showing us your data sample would be great.

Comment: this is a data simple  [["jazz",6],["pop",8]]

Comment: Just tested: `getSeries([["jazz",6],["pop",8]])` and in JS console I get: `[{"name":"jazz","data":[6,0]},{"name":"pop","data":[0,8]}]` - so the output is proper. Don't use `alert()` because it displays data as string not as "true form" of the object.

Answer (score -1):

Try using eval. Ex.

data: eval(data)